# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'citipy' error

Tags: python, api, openweathermap

I was trying to do a weather api related python program and initially while running the dependencies there was a error that occurred which reads as 
`'No module named 'citipy' error'`.

But i used `from citipy import city` command initially and even installed citipy using `pip install citipy` and upgraded it too.

The error still persists. Please help.

Comment: could you please add the output of `pip freeze` and the directory structure in which your file is OR the shell is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by just changing the kernel. I don't know how kernel affects when your trying to import a module, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had initially installed citipy through git bash, but when I ran my code in jupyter notebook it did not run. To solve the problem I had to install citipy through anaconda prompt (which is how I open my jupyter notebook) and I think this is how both the citipy and your code are in the same kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're importing the module and then running it with different names.

If you run

```
from citypy import city
```

Then all you're actually importing is city, not citypy, and similarly, you call its functions with city, not citypy.

If you want to run something from citypy that isn't in city, you can import it as:

```
import citypy
```

If you need more help, paste the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same to me, and I noticed that I skipt to activate pythondata from anaconda prompt